# Devise does not set notice messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cucumber

My app is rather barebones right now, so it might be a very stupid mistake by my side. I'm testing with cucumber signing out with devise

```
Scenario: User signs out
  Given I am logged in
  When I sign out
  Then I should see a signed out message
```

Everything is pretty standard, I've set devise to accept get requests for signing out, and from my logs everything appears to work as expected. Only problem is the last step, the flash/notice message doesn't show up, which is very weird (as always with devise, I don't know who's setting what and where...).

This is my layout view:

```
%body
  - unless notice.blank?
    %p.notice= notice
  - unless alert.blank?
    %p.alert= alert
  = yield
```

What I see is a completely blank page... I've already checked locales, the message is there. The sign_out call is the standard one. Flash messages appear to be completely empty (blank).

What course of action would you suggest I take in order to debug this?

Comment: have you tried seeing if the flash hash contains anything? flash[:notice] etc.

Comment: Yes I did, and it appears to be empty. Thanks.

Comment: To whoever edited my question, the library name is "Devise", https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. The question was correct, and after the edit is not, it doesn't even make sense: which device should set these messages?

Comment: when you sign out do you see any double redirects in your server log?